# In Django, Handling hashtag class didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, twitter

I have started learning Django, I'm not sure how to handle **HttpResponseRedirect()**.

Here is the code snippet of the *profile.html*.

```
<form method="post" action="post/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.text.errors }}
        {{ form.text }}
    </div>
    {{ form.country.as_hidden }}
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="post">
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see on the snippet code, when I click submit button, it goes to  **http://localhost:8000/user/sapphire/post/** I guess.

Here is the snippet code in *urls.py*.

```
from tweets.views import PostTweet

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', Profile.as_view()),
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/post/$', PostTweet.as_view()),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

As you can see, when I click submit button, we navigate to the **PostTweet** class in views.py.

Here is the snippet code in *views.py*.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from .models import Tweet
from user_profile.models import User
from .forms import TweetForm

class PostTweet(View):
    def post(self, request, username):
        form = TweetForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.get(username = username)
            tweet = Tweet(text = form.cleaned_data['text'], user = user, country = form.cleaned_data['country'])
            tweet.save()
            words = form.cleaned_data['text'].spilt(" ")
            for word in words:
                if word[0] == "#":
                    hashtag, created = HashTag.objects.get_or_create(name = word[1:])
                    hastag.tweet.add(tweet)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/' + username)
```

As you can see, when I click submit button, I guess it goes to **http://localhost:8000/user/sapphire/**, and render another **tweet** I have added. *But it doesn't work, exception occurs*.

> ValueError at /user/sapphire/post/, Exception Value: The view tweets.views.PostTweet didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

How can I handle it. To be honest, I'm not sure what HashTag means. In another tutorial, in order to use hashtag in django, I have to install and setup hashtag module, but I didn't. Please tell me how I handle this error and get idea of hashtag.

**Thanks for your time.**

Comment: There is definetly something wrong here. You are using HTTPResponseRedirect but you have not imported it. I guess python is not reaching upto that line or it would show "not defined" error.

Comment: Neither your error or code contain anything at all to do with HashTag. Why do you mention it?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've imported **from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect** on the top of views.py file, but same exception occurs. Please tell me why.

Comment: Hi, Daniel, I mean ** hashtag, created = HashTag.objects.get_or_create(name = word[1:])**. I'm not sure **hashtag** & **HashTag.objects**.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't using a Named Group in your URL.

If you add username to the URL:
`^user/(?P<username>[\w+])/$'`
you should be able to use that value in the view.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I wrote the url like as above, 'can't import username pattern' exception has occurred.

Comment: I edited my initial answer. There should have been [] around the regex

Comment: Hi. Christopher. Thanks again. I'm beginner, would you tell me more exactly? what do you mean by **(?P<username>[\w+])**. I know only (\w+).

Comment: The first URL will capture the information that you put within it, but with the second one it captures that information but passes it as a keyword argument that you can pass to the view.  The second one follows this pattern:  (?P<name>pattern).  Here is the documentation for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/.  Based off the view.py you had, it didn't look like you were ever assigning a value to username which could have been part of your issue.

Comment: I got it. So how can I fix it? I have already changed url as **url(r'^user/ (?P<username>[\w+])/post/$', PostTweet.as_view()),** but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Are you still seeing the same error 'can't import username pattern'?

Comment: Same exception has occurred. I guess the problem is hashtag. If I go to **http://localhost:8000/user/sapphire**, browser shows form and <div>tag. When I fill the text area such as *I'm Feeling #Lucky*, then click submit button, it goes to **http://localhost:8000/user/sapphire/post** and exception occurs as described above.

Comment: In another tutorial, it says when I use hashtag, I have to install hashtag module, but In this tutorial, I didn't install hashtag, but I use it like  *hashtag, created = HashTag.objects.get_or_create(name = word[1:])*, *hastag.tweet.add(tweet)*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144599/discussion-between-christopher-mallon-and-yuiry-kozlenko).